Is there a way for random term extraction when searching COCA (the Corpus of Contemporary American English)?
When I search for 1000 examples of maybe using COCA data, most of the data that comes up is from older years.
How can I obtain data that is randomly extracted based on the era in which it was used, genre, etc.?
I've looked into it but I can't figure it out.
